# Django getting data from database using foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am working on a django blog app and i want to access all the fields of database through foreign key of other database .

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    about_user = models.TextField(("Profile"),blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
    

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey("account.User",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.BooleanField(("Status"),default = False)
```

Now I want to access all the data of user database from post something like

`posts = Post.objects.filter(status = True)`
posts.author.about_author

or

user  = User.objects.filter(username = post.author)
user.about_author

what i am trying here in my template all the content of post will display and after that i want the about_author (whoever wrote the post ).kinda like how stackoverflow shows every questions.

Thanks in advance and any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fetch the `Post`s with:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(status=True)
```

but it makes no sense to write:

```
posts.author
```

since `posts` is a `QuerySet` (so a *collection*) of `Post`s, not a single one.

You can enumerate over the `posts` and then show the `.author`s for all `Post` objects:

```
for post in posts:
    print(post.author.about_user)
```

or in the template with:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.author.about_user }}
{% endfor %}
```

You can boost efficiency by fetching all the `User`s in the same query with:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(status=True).select_related('author')
```